# Zero extension of a $W^{2,\infty}$ Sobolev function outside its domain

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $O$ be a non empty  open subset of a bounded open set $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f\in L^2(\Omega)\cap W^{2,\infty}(O)$. Let $u: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that the function $g$ defined by 
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}u(x),\quad &x\in O \\ 0,\quad &x\in \Omega\setminus O\end{cases} $$ 
is an element of   ${\cal C}^2(\overline{\Omega})$.

Let $h$ be defined by 
$$h(x)=
\begin{cases} u(x) f(x), \quad &x\in O\\  0,\quad & x\in \Omega\setminus O\end{cases} $$

Do we have $h \in W^{2,\infty}(\Omega)$?

Comment: A function in $W^{2,\infty}$ is continuously differentiable with Lipschitz gradient. So you can apply the chain rule to $\nabla (uf)$ and conclude the same about $uf$.